# How do i rotate every word in a sentence according to their indexes?

Tags: java

I am trying to read an input file containing two sentences on new line. I have to write a code to rotate every word in a sentence to the right side and write to output.txt file. For example, input.txt file contains following:

```
Hello World.
Welcome to java programming.
```

Let's say "Hello" has index 1. It should rotate to the right by one character i.e. **oHell**. "World." has index 2, it should rotate to the right by 2 characters i.e. **ldWor.**, maintaining the position of period(.)

And on the next line index again begins with 1. i.e. "Welcome" with index 1 should rotate to the right by 1 character, "to" with index 2 should rotate to the right by 2 characters, "java" with index 3 should rotate to the right by 3 characters, "programming" with index 4 should rotate to the right by 4 characters.

So, the output should be:

```
oHell ldWor.
eWelcom to avaj mingprogram.
```

So far, I have managed to read the file and store the words in array list. And, I am stuck with rotation logic. Below is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        FileInputStream inputFile = new FileInputStream("input.txt");
        FileWriter outputFile = new FileWriter("output.txt");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(inputFile);
        //System.out.println("Enter a Sentence");

        while(scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            String str = scanner.nextLine();
            String str1[] = str.split(" ");
            ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(str1));
            for(int i = 0; i < words.size(); i++) {
                System.out.print((i+1)+":"+words.get(i)+"\n");
                outputFile.write((i+1)+"\t");
                outputFile.write(words.get(i)+"\n");
            }
        }
        inputFile.close();
        outputFile.close();
        scanner.close();
     }
```

Here, I am just trying to print the array list to output file to see if I am able to write it to file.

Can anyone help? Thanks.

Comment: And the actual output is ...... ?

Comment: `c.toString();` prints nothing because it returns a `String`, you need to call `System.out.println(c);` - that will invoke the `toString()` for you (so you can omit that). same with `cc.toString();` - basically, if you want `test()` to print something, you have to print something.

Comment: Also, what's the point of creating a bunch of cars in a list and then completely ignoring them in `test` and creating a bunch of new ones?

Comment: It would be nice if you could reduce this to [a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). I realize it’s easier said than done. It’s also difficult to tell what goes in in a program when we only see half of it.

Comment: Your implementation is probably fine. As @ElliottFrisch says, you just need your test to print something.

Comment: I suggest you look for "Scope of local variables". Here is a great link: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/variable-scope-in-java/

Comment: Suggest you start by writing a function that takes a word and returns the rotated version. `private static String rotate(String word, int places) {...}`. Then have you main function use that.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using java 8 or higher this would solve your problem.

```
    import java.io.FileInputStream;
    import java.io.FileWriter;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.util.Scanner;
    import java.util.stream.Collectors;
    import java.util.stream.IntStream;

    public class Test {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
            rotate();
        }

        private static void rotate() throws IOException {
            FileInputStream inputFile = new FileInputStream("input.txt");
            FileWriter outputFile = new FileWriter("output.txt");
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(inputFile);

            while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                String line = scanner.nextLine();
                String last = "";
                if(line.charAt(line.length()-1) == '.'){
                    last = ".";
                    line = line.substring(0,line.length()-1);
                }
                String str[] = line.split(" ");
                outputFile.write(IntStream.range(0, str.length).mapToObj(i -> rotate(str[i], i+1)).collect(Collectors.joining(" ")) +last+ "\n");
            }
            inputFile.close();
            outputFile.close();
            scanner.close();
        }

        private static String rotate(String str, int position) {
            return str.substring(str.length()-position)+str.substring(0,str.length()-position);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Its throwing an StringIndexOutOfBoundException

Comment: I resolved StringIndexOutOfBoundException by modifying outputFile.write(IntStream.range(0, str.length-1).mapToObj(i -> rotate(str[i], i)).collect(Collectors.joining(" ")) +last+ "\n");

Comment: Output that i am getting now : Hello.
Welcome ot vaja.

Comment: Its skipping the last words in both the sentence. Also, first word doesn't rotate

Comment: @Coder I was away for last few days. So I couldn't reply. I have tested the code for only the sample data that you provided. With this code you can get main idea and improve it to suite for you requirement. I'm happy if you could solve your problem. :)